# Enabling Toolbar SSRS report PHP

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have managed to successfully buid a **SSRS reporting server** and connect my PHP application to render a report from it. The report is getting displayed in the browser but I **do not see a toolbar** at the top which handles page numbers, exporting etc. I have followed [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/brian_swan/archive/2010/05/04/getting-started-with-sql-server-reporting-services-ssrs-and-php.aspx) URL to set up everything. Am I missing something? 
I am getting Something like this:

> [image: Current Situation]

I want Something like this

> [image: Desired Result]

Comment: @hims056 Have u worked on SSRS Wid PHP ?

Comment: No. I just edited your post and improved formatting. Also, crop both images and show only table (remove empty white background).

Answer (score 0):

Please add &rc:Toolbar=true to the report url